# Content Not Displaying on Hover

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

On my wordpress site I have different images displayed that link to different posts, when you hover over the image a green box covers the image and white text (information about the post) is displayed on the box. For some reason this only works on 6/7 of the images. The information that needs to be displayed is being correctly pulled from the database, but for some reason it just is not being displayed.
This is what im using in the PHP template to display the image and information:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
<div id="home-overlay-outer">
   <div class="home-overlay">
       <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
       <p><?php echo $location; ?> &mdash; <?php echo $specifics; ?></p>
   </div>
</div>
</a>
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
```

[This is what happens when you hover over the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wV98.png)

Im at a loss as to what could cause this when it works fine on every other image.

CSS used for the hover and boxes: https://jsfiddle.net/5w3svfoc/

Comment: Instead of providing the logic that builds the markup, it is more helpful to provide the markup that is generated.  Also including the logic that actually deals with the hover would be very helpful.

Comment: Usually with a CSS question you should provide the CSS code for the supplied HTML. Can you please add the styles for the posted HTML?

Comment: CSS for the overlay has been added. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using IDs as selectors for this. You should be using class based selectors in this case. This may explain the 6/7 problem. Also, you shouldn't have a `:hover` selector on an element with `display: none;`. Consider putting the hover selector on the parent, and making sure it has width and height. Toggle the content display based on the hover selector, but not the hovered element itself.

```css
.hover-images .image {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}

.hover-images .hover-content {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.hover-images .hover-show-content:hover .hover-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-images">
  <div id="hover1" class="image hover-show-content">
    <div class="hover-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="hover2" class="image hover-show-content">
    <div class="hover-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```